# SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many - middle table insertion

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an issue when adding a items through relationship in SQLAlchemy.

My model

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Order(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'orders' 

id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    primary_key=True,
    autoincrement = True
)

user_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('users.id'),
    nullable = False
)

timestamp = db.Column(        
    db.DateTime,
    nullable=False,
    default=datetime.utcnow()
)

total = db.Column(
    db.Float,
    nullable = False
)

products = db.relationship('Product', secondary = 'orders_products', backref = 'orders')


class OrderProduct(db.Model):
'''Mapping Order to Product'''

__tablename__ = 'orders_products'

id = db.Column(
    db.Integer, 
    primary_key = True,
    autoincrement = True
)

order_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey('orders.id'),
    primary_key = True
)

product_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey('products.id'),
    primary_key = True
)

quantity = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    nullable = False
)`
```

Execution:

```
cart = session[CART]
user = g.user
products = []

for c in cart:
    products.append(
        [Product.query.get_or_404(c.get('product_id')), c.get('quantity')]
    )

order = Order()

        for p in products:
            total += p[0].price
            order.products.append(p[0])
            order.product_quantity.append(OrderProduct(quantity= p[1]))

        order.user_id = user.id

        db.session.add(order)
        db.session.commit()
```

Once values passed and method runs, the result I am having is two independent instances in orders_products table for each order.
Orders table:

```
select * from orders;
id | user_id |         timestamp         | total
----+---------+---------------------------+-------
 1 |       1 | 2023-03-19 21:36:20.03719 |  3.25
```

And in orders_products table I have:

```
select * from orders_products;
order_product_id | order_id | product_id | quantity
------------------+----------+------------+----------
               1 |        1 |          1 |
               2 |        1 |            |        3
```

What should I use in order to have a single instance in orders_products table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was suggested to use this way to walk around the issue:

```
order = Order(user_id=user.id, total=total)
        db.session.add(order)
        db.session.flush()

        for p in products:
            order_product = OrderProduct(order_id=order.id, 
                            product_id=p[0].id,quantity= p[1])
            db.session.add(order_product)
        
        db.session.commit()
```

The db.session.flush() will make an "id reservation" in a database before actual commit and after it will prepare values for middle table to insert based on id the was "reserved".

However, I believe it will not work smoothly if you have more than one user using and app. Or I am wrong here?